# Handling Username / Password between HTML and C

Tags: html, c, post, cgi

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to handle username / passwords from my HTML page. I've set up a basic page which uses:

```
<form action="myCFile.cgi" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Create Account" />
```

This information is sent to myCFile.cgi which of course in my actual code is an exact http address. I've confirmed that the information is successfully passed to the C file. Within this file I want to be able to check if that username already exists in an .ssv file that I have created (which is in the format: username password), and if it does not, I wish to append the document with the username and password information.
My trouble comes in trying to identify exactly what information being passed is the username. When "post" is used I know it sends information in the form:

```
username=xyz&password=abc
```

What is the best way to extract the username "xyz" from the above given that I won't know the length of the username? I want to stick only to C.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `strtok_s()` or non-standard `strtok_r()` and `strcmp()`. Details left as an exercise for the reader.
Also, details of URLDecode are not handled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
strchr(text, '=')
strchr(text, '&')
```

(see [C++ referrence](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/) to locate the borders of UN and PW. Be aware that these characters are encoded if part of the password (e. g. '&' is '%26').

Comment: The answer should be C, so do not link a "C++ reference" but the "C standard".

Comment: True - I used the C++ reference as the function is explained good there. Still it exists in the C standard, too. Should have mentioned it in the response, though...